# $\int_0^\infty x^n e^{-x^{12}\sin^2x}dx$ is divergent for any natural numbers $n$?

Tags: improper-integrals

$\int_0^\infty x^n e^{-x^{12}\sin^2x}dx$ is divergent for any natural numbers $n$? My attempt: Cauchy criteria near $2k\pi$ for integers $k$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}\int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi}e^{-x^{12}\sin^2x}\,\mathrm dx 
&= \int_0^\pi e^{-(k\pi+x)^{12}\sin^2x}\,\mathrm dx \\
&> \int_0^\pi e^{-((k+1)\pi)^{12}x^2}\,\mathrm dx \\
&= \int_0^\pi e^{-\pi^{10}((k+1)^6x)^2}\,\mathrm dx \\
&> \int_0^{\frac1{(k+1)^6}} e^{-\pi^{10}((k+1)^6x)^2}\,\mathrm dx \\
&> \int_0^{\frac1{(k+1)^6}} e^{-\pi^{10}}\,\mathrm dx \\
&=\frac{e^{-\pi^{10}}}{(k+1)^6}
\end{align} $$
so that you will readily find that the integral diverges at least for $n\ge 6$.

Comment: For a more precise result, I think one can use [Laplace's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method) to get $\int_{k \pi-\pi/2}^{k\pi+\pi/2} x^n \exp(-x^{12}\sin^2(x))\sim C (k \pi)^{n-6}$ when $k\to\infty$.

Comment: It seems that for $1\leq n<6$, the integral is also divergent. But I can not prove it.